# Finding child data based on parent id in sails (waterline ORM)

Tags: javascript, orm, nested, sails.js, waterline

I have a simple user model defined in sailsj as shown below. The only thing of note is that a User has a reference to a User as their manager. What I am attempting to understand, is how could I query this model such that it will return  users, and if any of those users are managers, then also include those sub-users, so on and so forth.

In oracle there was a "connect by prior" condition, however, I have not been successful in finding something for sails (or waterline).

```
module.exports = {

 attributes: {

  username: {
    type: 'string',
    unique: 'true',
    required: 'true'
  },

  systemRoleCd: {
    type: 'string',
    enum: ['normal', 'admin']
  },

  firstName: {
    type: 'string'
  },

  lastName: {
    type: 'string'
  },

  //The users direct manager
  manager: {
    model: 'User'
  },

  email: {
    type: 'string',
    email: 'true',
    unique: 'true'
  },

  //This is the encrypted password
  password: {
     type: 'string'
  },

  deleted: {
    type: 'boolean'
  }
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With assumption: a user may have at most one manager, and may have many subordinates.

Try this in `models/User.js`:

```
subordinates: {
  collection: 'user',
  via: 'manager'
},

manager: {
  model: 'user'
}
```

With [.populate()](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/populate), user's manager and subordinates should be returned.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, I'll try this and let you know the outcome. Thanks for the suggestion!